# Is it possible to provide absolute path to submodule but with same host as parent repository?

Tags: git, url, git-submodules, relative-path

I know the concept of relative URLs to submodules but I wonder if it's possible to have an absolute *path* but with same server/protocol/user.

This is how I configure absolute and relative URLs for submodules:

```
[submodule "mymodule"]
path = mymodule
url = ssh://git@myserver.com/path/mymodule.git  # absolute

[submodule "mymodule"]
path = mymodule
url = ../../some/path/mymodule.git  # relative
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
[submodule "mymodule"]
path = mymodule
url = @/path/mymodule.git  # only protocol/domain/user/port taken from parent
```

This feels like it should exist but I haven't seen something like this in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/2.4.4#_commands)..